# Update SQL Server HierarchyId in after insert trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, hierarchy, hierarchyid

I'm developing a message center in a information system, and today user Eric suggested use hierarchyid datatype to track the message reply, because the objective is to show as a Outlook or Gmail conversation.

To simplify, I've in my database table Messages:

```
MessageId int PK
ReplyToId int FK null
Subject varchar
Body varchar
Hierarchy hierarchyid
```

When a new message is inserted, I've a trigger to do the update.

I've inserted a new message, and the hierarchy is null, because is the first message, and isn't a reply.

If a try to insert a reply to that message, the hierarchyid still null... :(

My trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_UpdateHierarchy] 
   ON  [dbo].[Messages]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here

    DECLARE @replyId int
    SELECT @replyId = inserted.ReplyId
    FROM inserted
    IF(@replyId IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        RETURN
    END

    DECLARE @parent hierarchyid
    SELECT @parent = Hierarchy
    FROM   [Messages]
    WHERE  [Messages].MessageId = @replyId


    DECLARE @currentHierarchy hierarchyid = @parent.GetDescendant(null, null).ToString()
    DECLARE @messageId int
    SELECT @messageId = inserted.MessageId
        FROM inserted
    UPDATE [Messages]
        SET Hierarchy = @currentHierarchy
        WHERE [Messages].MessageId = @messageId
END
GO
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Another point, I've read about the index, but depth-first don't fit because have many with null value, because the first message from a conversation has null value, and bread-first is the best index type to has a better performance? Or I can discard this index?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I've updated the trigger, but don't do the `hierarchyid` in right way.

Now the trigger is:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_UpdateHierarchy] 
   ON  [dbo].[Messages]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    DECLARE @messageId int
    DECLARE @ParentId int
    SELECT  @messageId = inserted.MessageId,
            @ParentId = inserted.ParentId
        FROM inserted

    IF(@ParentId IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [Messages]
                SET Hierarchy = hierarchyid::GetRoot()
                WHERE [Messages].MessageId = @messageId
            RETURN
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @parent hierarchyid
            SELECT @parent = Hierarchy
                FROM   [Messages]
                WHERE  [Messages].MessageId = @ParentId

            DECLARE @lastHierarchy hierarchyid
            SELECT @lastHierarchy = MAX(Hierarchy) 
                FROM [Messages] 
                WHERE Hierarchy.GetAncestor(1) = @parent

            UPDATE [Messages]
                SET Hierarchy = @parent.GetDescendant(@lastHierarchy, NULL)
                WHERE [Messages].MessageId = @messageId
        END
END
```

If I insert messages like `id = 2` has `parentId = 1`, and `id = 3` has `parentId = 2` have this hierarchy:
`id = 1, hierarchy = \

id = 2, hierarchy = \1\

id = 3, hierarchy = \1\1\`

The first and second record has the right hierarchy, but next one no... :(

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That actually *is* one correct hierarchy implementation. However, it has limitations with batched inserts, but that's another issue .. also, it might make sense to *start* all "roots" with `\x`, or one level-deep, so the conversations do not share a parent tree.

In any case, insert a 2nd node with `id = 4, parentId = 2`, then it should look like `hierarchy = \1\2` (it is on the same hierarchy level, but after `\1\1`).

The values shown in the `hierarchy` "string" form *do not* need to relate to the `parentId` value!